# Recyclerview is only showing (and duplicating) the last child from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Anyone know why my recyclerview is only displaying the last child from my Firebase database? Apart from this, it's also duplicating this child in the recyclerview. I already changed `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

*Database Tree* - every child under "results" has children with the names "datum" "schietResultaat1" and so on.. In my case it's only getting the last child of "results".

[image]

*Here is where I access and save the children of "results" in a sharedPref*

```
DataSnapshot resultSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("results");
for (DataSnapshot ds: resultSnapshot.getChildren()) {

    String datumStr = ds.child("datum").getValue(String.class);
    String result1 = ds.child("schietResultaat1").getValue(String.class);
    String result2 = ds.child("schietResultaat2").getValue(String.class);
    String result3 = ds.child("schietResultaat3").getValue(String.class);
    String result4 = ds.child("schietResultaat4").getValue(String.class);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("datum", datumStr);
    editor.putString("schietResultaat1", result1);
    editor.putString("schietResultaat2", result2);
    editor.putString("schietResultaat3", result3);
    editor.putString("schietResultaat4", result4);
    editor.apply();
}
```

*Here is where I retrieve those children and assign them*

```
    myResultsList = resultsView.findViewById(R.id.results_list);
    myResultsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    resultsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Results> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Results>()
            .setQuery(resultsRef, Results.class)
            .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Results, ResultsViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Results, ResultsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Results model) {

            resultsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    SharedPreferences sp = getContext().getSharedPreferences("sp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String datumStr = sp.getString("datum", "");
                    String result1 = sp.getString("schietResultaat1", "");
                    String result2 = sp.getString("schietResultaat2", "");
                    String result3 = sp.getString("schietResultaat3", "");
                    String result4 = sp.getString("schietResultaat4", "");

                    byte[] result1AsBytes = Base64.decode(result1, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedResult1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result1AsBytes, 0, result1AsBytes.length);
                    byte[] result2AsBytes = Base64.decode(result2, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedResult2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result2AsBytes, 0, result2AsBytes.length);
                    byte[] result3AsBytes = Base64.decode(result3, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedResult3 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result3AsBytes, 0, result3AsBytes.length);
                    byte[] result4AsBytes = Base64.decode(result4, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedResult4 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result4AsBytes, 0, result4AsBytes.length);

                    holder.datum.setText(datumStr);
                    holder.resultaat1.setImageBitmap(decodedResult1);
                    holder.resultaat2.setImageBitmap(decodedResult2);
                    holder.resultaat3.setImageBitmap(decodedResult3);
                    holder.resultaat4.setImageBitmap(decodedResult4);

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    throw error.toException();
                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ResultsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.result_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new ResultsViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    myResultsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

Comment: please use documentation ... obviously in `onBindViewHolder` you should use `@NonNull Results model` not `resultsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent` nor data from `SharedPreferences`

Comment: @Selvin still the same bro